# Something goes wrong during the first for loop

Tags: python

I end up with the output: 2,1,8,0,0,   It should be: 2,1,3,1,4,   I'm using PyCharm CE 2016.2.3 and Python 3.6.6   Thank you for your time!

```
lotto = {
    '1': 0,
    '2': 0,
    '3': 0,
    '4': 0,
    '5': 0
}

test_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]

for i in test_list:
    if test_list[i] == 1:
        lotto['1'] += 1
    if test_list[i] == 2:
        lotto['2'] += 1
    if test_list[i] == 3:
        lotto['3'] += 1
    if test_list[i] == 4:
        lotto['4'] += 1
    if test_list[i] == 5:
        lotto['5'] += 1

for i in lotto:
    print(lotto[i], end=",")
```

Comment: Change `test_list[i] == 1` to `i==1`.

Comment: The `for ... in ...` loop does not index the list but iterate through every item in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. Especially for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to replace test_list[i] with just i because i is already iterating through test_list and checking each number, not the index. Also, just for good practice, after the first if block, change each if to elif.

```
lotto = {
    '1': 0,
    '2': 0,
    '3': 0,
    '4': 0,
    '5': 0
}
test_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]

for i in test_list:
    if i == 1:
        lotto['1'] = lotto['1'] + 1
    elif i == 2:
        lotto['2'] += 1
    elif i == 3:
        lotto['3'] += 1
    elif i == 4:
        lotto['4'] += 1
    elif i == 5:
        lotto['5'] += 1
    i+=1

for i in lotto:
    print(lotto[i], end=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be:

```
lotto = {
    '1': 0,
    '2': 0,
    '3': 0,
    '4': 0,
    '5': 0
}
test_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]

for i in test_list:
    i = str(i)
    lotto[i] = lotto[i] + 1

for i in lotto:
    print(lotto[i], end=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Brown !

You can replace the for loop with a better way to use lists in python:

```
for number in test_list:
    lotto[str(number)] += 1
```

Use numbers in test_list to refer in key value.

```
lotto = {
'1': 0,
'2': 0,
'3': 0,
'4': 0,
'5': 0 }

test_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]

for number in test_list:
   lotto[str(number)] += 1
```

And the result is:

```
{'1': 2, '2': 1, '3': 3, '4': 1, '5': 4}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's amazing to see how everyone does something a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-implemented your code with `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
test_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
lotto = Counter(map(str, test_list))
print(','.join(map(str, lotto.values())))
```